# Difference between "circumstance" and "event" in the definitions of threat

Tags: terminology, threats

On the [Wikipedia page of threat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threat_(computer)) (in textbooks too) various definitions are given where almost all agree in defining a threat as a "circumstance or event".

I'm having trouble understanding the subtle difference between event and circumstance. What is an example of an event that is not a circumstance? And what is an example of a circumstance that is not an event?

Comment: An existing vulnerability in a product is a circumstance. It is a threat even if currently nobody exploits it since it might get exploited in the future. Someone attacking a system is an event, which is clearly a threat too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Circumstance](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/circumstance)

> - a condition, fact, or event accompanying, conditioning, or determining another
> - a piece of evidence that indicates the probability or improbability of an event
> - the sum of essential and environmental factors

The connotation here is that a "circumstance" is the "pre-condition" for a hazard.

So, an unlocked door is a *circumstance*. Someone walking through the door without authorisation is an *event*. In both cases, nothing bad has happened *yet*. But both represent a threat because they both proceed loss.

Other circumstances that are threats:

- unpatched systems
- distracted users
- untested backups

Comment: Makes sense. What about "circumstance or event" used in the definition of the [four kinds of threat consequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threat_(computer)#Threat_consequence), based on [RFC 4949](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4949)? Aren't they just events? What makes them circumstances?

Comment: You can think of them as "pre-events".